# Is there a way to make a content template in Twig?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, markdown

In the past, I've used Twig to loop through posts and pull meta from each post and display product lists. For instance, I had 25 pages in a folder and each page had a title, feature-img, and short description. I made a page template with twig to loop through every page and then pulled each bit of meta and displayed in a structure that I liked:

---

Image----Title

description here

---

Now, I'm trying to make a few lists as pages. So, I don't want to create 20 product pages and loop through all pages, I just want to list 20 products on a page.  However, the styling is going to be a real pain to keep copy and pasting over in a .md file.  Is there a way to make a product.html.twig file and then do something like this inside of a markdown file?

```
Name:
Img:
Description:

Name:
Img:
Description:

Name:
Img:
Description:
```

And have the page pull the template around it at render?

---

To clarify, I'm using philecms and using html page templates with twig tags.  I'mm about to make a lot of pages that list products. I don't want each product to have its own page, I could easily loop through all product pages and display with twig. Instead, each product is going to be a section of content within a .md file.

Comment: Can you describe your Doctrine Entities better? For example, I guess you have a Product, but what getters and setters does it have? How do you get the Name/Img/Description shown above?

Comment: @AlvinBunk every product listing is actually being done by hand without using a database.

Comment: you want to put the output of twig inside a md file?

Comment: @DarkBee I've been using Twig + markdown through PhileCMS. So, there is one {{ content }} block in my twig page template that grabs the contents of a md file. I can easily use twig to loop through multiple md files and grab their meta info & content, but I'm about to build some 1 page lists and want to re-use blocks of identical html over and over again.

Comment: To reuse a template you can use [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/include.html)

Comment: @DarkBee yeah, I know. I'm trying to use a template multiple times for content in a .md file, and it doesn't seem like I can use twig loops inside a md file